# usb_cam node "permission denied" when launched by robot_upstart

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch `usb_cam` from a launch file with `robot_upstart` on boot, the node fails saying:

```
[usb_cam-4] process has died [pid 3136, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/68608950-115a-11e6-805a-544a16bf53a7/usb_cam-4.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/68608950-115a-11e6-805a-544a16bf53a7/usb_cam-4*.log
```

When I look at that log it says:

```
[ WARN] [1462299217.838001270]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1462299217.874595145]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
[ WARN] [1462299240.126186614]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1462299240.141871614]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
[ WARN] [1462299353.880653169]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1462299353.909079127]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

When I launch the node using rosrun, it works perfectly. What could be causing this issue? I am running ROS Indigo on a Beaglebone Black and Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233527/usb_cam-node-%22permission-denied%22-when-launched-by-robot_upstart/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I launch the node using rosrun, it works perfectly. What could be causing this issue?

Have you read the note about permissions in the installation documentation? From the [robot_upstart 0.2.0 documentation » The install script - permissions](http://docs.ros.org/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html#permissions):

> It’s important to understand how permissions work robot_upstart:

> 1. The upstart job invokes its `jobname-start` bash script as root.

> 1. The script sets up environment variables, and then uses setuidgid to execute roslaunch as an unprivileged user. This is by default the user who ran the install script, but it can also be specified explicitly via a flag.

> 1. **The roslaunch which executes does not have its user’s group memberships**. This means that it will **not have access to serial ports with the `dialout` group**, or locations in /var/log owned by root, etc. Any filesystem resources needed by your ROS nodes should be chowned to the same unprivileged user which will run ROS, or should set to world readable/writeable, for example using udev.

So `jobname-start` starts out as user `root`, but then quickly drops all privileges and continues as a regular user (that is not a member of the `dialout` or any other group). There may be some more configuration required.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-05-03**:
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-05-03**:
Though, how would I make the serial and video available on the robot then?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-04**:
Wouldn't this come down to figuring out which user is actually used by `robot_upstart`, and then making that user a member of the `dialout` or `video` group? That is essentially what bullet point nr 3 states, right?

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-05-04**:
From the way I read it, no. At least to me, it seems to say that if user X is a member of dialout and robot_upstart uses that user, it will not have access to the dialout group, even though the user is part of it. Am I wrong, or is there a way to get around this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-04**:
You're right:

> [..] should be chowned to the same unprivileged user which will run ROS, or should set to world readable/writeable, for example using udev. [..]

I guess that is one approach, use `udev` to chown the device files (or make them world readable/writable).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that your user is not a part of the `video` group and so it does not have permission to open the video device.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823374

Edit: I haven't used robot_upstart but perhaps it launches ROS as a different user than the one you are logging in with and it is not in the `video` group.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-05-03**:
Thanks for your help!